# Wordpress Plugin Taxonomy URL 404 Error

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, taxonomy

I'm creating a plugin for a project and that plugin has a custom taxonomy called "listings", here's how I registered it:

```
add_action('init', function(){
register_taxonomy( 'listings', 'listings', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Listings', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Listings', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Listings' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Listings' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Listings' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Listings:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Listings' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Listings' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Listings' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Listings Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Listings Categories' ),
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'          => 'listings',
            'with_front'    => true
        )
    )); 
});
```

When I try to access the URL "`http://myprojecturl/listings/some-category`" I get a 404 error. What's happening? I'm really new with wordpress.

Comment: do you have it wrapped in a function and using `init` to `add_action` ?? i am assuming you have a custom post type created called `listings` is that valid?

Comment: @DavidChase Yes, I have! `register_post_type( 'listings' , $args );`

Comment: are you saying you registered the taxonomy twice??

Comment: First I created the plugin, than I registered a new post type to show on the dashboard and then I created a new taxonomy. Is that wrong?

Comment: from the looks of it above it seems like you used `register_taxonomy` twice for the same data? or no?

Comment: I fixed it, I just did once. Can you add me on Skype? raafael.fragoso

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27887/discussion-between-david-chase-and-rafael-fragoso)